# How to sort first before upcase-downcase in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This code is almost right, but I need to sort the inputs in alphabetical order before alternating between upcase and downcase.

```
football_team = []
5.times do |i|
  puts "Please enter a UK football team:"
  team = gets.chomp
  if i.even?
    football_team << team.upcase
  else
    football_team << team.downcase
  end
end

puts football_team
```

I cannot use `each_with_index`.

Comment: I think this question needs to show sample input and output.

Comment: @LukasBaliak it's spelt homework... the word you wrote could be misconstrued!

Comment: Why you cannot use `each_with_index` ? Its some kind of homework?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 sorry, its just typing error.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to sort the inputs in alphabetical order before alternating between upcase and downcase.

I can identify 3 parts:

1. collect input
2. sort alphabetical
3. upcase and downcase

Obviously, this can't be done in a single loop.

That being said, here's one way to separate your code:

Part 1:

```
teams = []

5.times do |i|
  puts "Please enter a UK football team:"
  teams << gets.chomp
end
```

Part 2:

```
teams.sort!
```

Part 3:

```
5.times do |i|
  if i.even?
    teams[i].upcase!
  else
    teams[i].downcase!
  end
end

puts teams
```

Comment: Your answer is well-explained. Just a query, in part 1 I think `gets.chomp` should be downcased perhaps? Or else the `sort` method in part 2 will put all the teams starting with capitals before those input as starting lowercase.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 raises a good point

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your answer, try this:

```
football_team = []
5.times do |i|
  puts "Please enter a UK football team:"
  team = gets.chomp.downcase
  football_team << team
end

final_index = football_team.size - 1
football_team.sort!

(0..final_index).each do |i|

    if i.even?
        football_team[i] = football_team[i].upcase
    else
        football_team[i] = football_team[i].downcase
    end

end

p football_team
```

Comment: The `for` loop is not really a Ruby idiom.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I agree. I'll see if I can muster up a more Ruby way and change the answer accordingly. But struggling to find one at the moment.

Comment: maybe use this ? `football_team[i] = football_team[i].send(i.even? ? "upcase" : "downcase")`

Comment: @LukasBaliak yes that would probably work but it may be a bit too cryptic for the OP who might be new to Ruby, but thanks.